# How to generate lib for a Visual C++ dll project

Tags: windows, visual-c++

I have a Visual C++ dll project. The dll can be created, but the lib isn't generated. Which project propery should I modify to ouput the lib?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Use a Module Defintion File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/d91k01sh):

- Add a DEF file to your DLL project, if it does not already have one.
- Verify that the DEF file is used as "Module Definition File".
- Add all symbols to be exported to the DEF file.

Alternatively you can use [`__declspec(dllexport)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a90k134d.aspx) to define exported symbols.

Answer (score 2):

Do you export some symbol?
Without exporting something, lib is not generated.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @user35443: For your comment, do you have clarification why this is not answer?

Comment: When will people finally realise that these comments are put under the post when somebody recommends a deletion. Just to show you what reviewers think of your answer: http://prntscr.com/57ab9v . 6/8 do recommend deletion.

Comment: I just wonder why is there so many closed or deleted answers with upvotes out there. Hmm, let me think... maybe because they're actually wrong, even though some people think they're good? Reviewers are those who decide whether answer should be deleted or not - not people with vote privileges (even monkey can get 15 rep).

Comment: "Reviewers are those who decide whether answer should be deleted or not - not people with vote privileges." If you disagree with this system, you can complain on meta, sure you'll get enough upvotes to prove your point :) go, try it.

Comment: @user35443: Hmmmmm, dear reviewer, so delete this, is your decision, as you wrote.

Comment: "Hmmmmm, dear reviewer, so **whether to** delete this, is your decision, as you wrote." See the difference? Let's take your previous comment as a brilliant example of this - I saw it here 10 hours ago, and now it's deleted, proving that it works.

Comment: @user35443: So delete answer. Now.

Comment: I'm waiting for the meaning of those highlighted words to become finally understood by you. It seems I'll be waiting for a long time.

Comment: @user35443: I am waiting when you stop write unnecessary comments. I know how review system on SO.com behave. I have two Reviewer badges. Problem is you dont understand answer nor question!

Comment: If you understand it so well, why do you argue if reviewer makes his decision. Try to find out why he did so and leave the comment be, don't reply just to "show you're right".